# Calculating features from one vector layer in another layer (grid)?

Tags: qgis, clip, vector-grid

I have two vector layers

- a landcover map showing the different habitats in a region
- a grid of 4 x 4 km squares that covers the region

[image: vector layer]

[image: grid layer]

I have to calculate the percentage of landcover in each grid square, so the percentage of what is in the landcover layer for each individual 4 x 4 km square.

How to achieve this in QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prerequisition: Your grid has a unique `id` attribute to identify the grid cells. If not so, you may create one using QGIS Field calculator like this:

[image]

Now you can intersect you landcover and grid with the *Intersection*-Tool (Processing Toolbox, search inters....):

[image]

It's easily configured and will assign the attributes of the grid cells (especially the `id`, see above)

[image]

You may verify this by setting up a categorized style on the id attribute of the resulting `Intersection` Layer.

[image]

Then run QGIS *Dissolve* (Processing Toolbox, again) on the result:

[image]

The QGIS Dissolve algorithm has the great advantage of being able to dissolve on various attributes. Dissolve on the referred `id` and your landuse classification attribute (mine is called `name`). Don't forget to uncheck 'Dissolve all':

[image]

In the resulting Layer, you can select a feature and see what happened, one multipolygon per landuse category and grid cell! Yay!!! (Note that the Dissolve Tool description is a bit misleading here, because it talks just about adjacent polygons...)

[image]

Now you're nearly done. The percentage area is simply calculated with the above mentioned *Field Calculator* by dividing each features `$area` by the grid cells area (mine are 1000 x 1000 = 1000000 map units). Because of possibly very small landuse areas I select a relatively high precision (6 digits) for the area percentage:

[image]

Having done so, save edits to your layer and have a look at the attribute table of the `Dissolved` Layer (note the attributes `name`,`id` and `area_perc`):

[image]

So far so good. The next step would be to create an attribute on the grid for each landuse category and fill in the `area_perc` values in order to e.g. draw pie charts etc.

Here we go. This little python script (quick and dirty I must confess...) accomplishes this task:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#---------Schnittstelle definieren
##[giswg]=group
##Create Attributes from Attribute values=name
##Attribute_value_provider=vector
##Field_to_query_attribute_values_from=field Attribute_value_provider
##Percent_values=field Attribute_value_provider
##Attributes_to_create=vector
##Matching_field=field Attributes_to_create

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from qgis.core import *
from processing import *

attrib_val_provider = processing.getObject(Attribute_value_provider)
layer_to_change = processing.getObject(Attributes_to_create)

#create attributes 
attr_id =     attrib_val_provider.fieldNameIndex(Field_to_query_attribute_values_from)
values = attrib_val_provider.uniqueValues(attr_id)
values.sort()
attributes = [QgsField(name, QVariant.Double) for name in values]
layer_to_change.dataProvider().addAttributes(attributes)
layer_to_change.updateFields()

#assign attribute values to the new features
attr_id = layer_to_change.fieldNameIndex(Matching_field)
ids = layer_to_change.uniqueValues(attr_id)
ids.sort()
for id in ids:
    # get feature from layer 2 to modify
    expr = QgsExpression('"{0}" = {1}'.format(Matching_field, id)) 
    feat = [f for f in layer_to_change.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))][0]
    fid = feat.id()
    attrs = {}
    for name in values:
        # get area percentage from layer 1
        expr = QgsExpression('"{0}" = \'{1}\' and "{2}" = {3}'.format(Field_to_query_attribute_values_from, name, Matching_field, id))
        feats = [f for f in attrib_val_provider.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))] #result should be only 1 feature
        if len(feats) == 1:
            area_perc = feats[0][Percent_values]
        elif len(feats) == 0:
            area_perc = 0.0
        attrs[layer_to_change.fieldNameIndex(name)] = area_perc * 100
    layer_to_change.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({fid : attrs})
    progress.setText('id {0} processed.'.format(id))
```

Copy+paste it, save it under `the_name_you_like.py` and add it to your processing scripts in the Processing toolbox under Scripts|Tools|Add script from file (select the file you just saved).

[image]

It should then be found under `[giswg]`:

[image]

Doubleclick to execute and select the appropriate parameters:

- landuse layer
- landuse category attribute
- area percentage attribute
- grid layer
- id attribute of grid cells

[image]

The log should do something like shown below during and after execution:

[image]

In the case of success, your grid layers attribute table should look something like shown below. **Important Note**: The percent values ranging from 0...100% come from the script, not from the field calculator above (0...1). This can either be done (if necessary) by the script **OR** the field calculator, not by both of them.

[image]

The values from 0...100% are required to create pie chart diagrams for the grid cells for example:

[image]